# Putting 2 rows of input fields in one column with Materialize Grids

Tags: html, css, forms, materialize, grid-layout

I'm trying to put 2 rows of input fields in one column using materialize grid so the text area on the right can expand without pushing the other input field. My problem is the input labels and icons of both rows overlaps each other.

[image: This is how it looks like]

My Code:

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col s12">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="input-field col s6">
                   <i class="material-icons prefix">account_circle</i>
                   <input id="value1" value="<?= $row['value1'];?>" type="text" class="validate">
                   <label for="value1">Value 1</label>
                   <i class="material-icons prefix">wc</i>
                   <input id="value2" value="<?= $row['value2'];?>" type="text" class="validate">
                   <label for="value2">Value 2</label>
            </div>

            <div class="input-field col s6">
                   <textarea id="block" class="materialize-textarea"><?=$row['textblock'];?></textarea>
                   <label for="block">Dynamic Block of text</label>
            </div>
        </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="col s6">
 <div class="input-field">
  <i class="material-icons prefix">account_circle</i>
  <input id="value1" value="<?= $row['value1'];?>" type="text" class="validate">
  <label for="value1">Value 1</label>
 </div>
 <div class="input-field">
  <i class="material-icons prefix">wc</i>
  <input id="value2" value="<?= $row['value2'];?>" type="text" class="validate">
  <label for="value2">Value 2</label>
 </div>
</div>
```

I solved it by placing both input fields under one div "col s6" then placing each input fields inside their own "input-field".